# Parsing images from JSON to listview in Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm having trouble loading images from my JSON file to the listview in Android

I understand I have to use BitmapFactory.decodeStream but beyond that I'm not really sure how to implement it

Here's my adapter and activity

```
public class JSON {

static InputStream is = null;

static String jsonString = "";

static JSONObject jObj = null;

public JSON() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String urlString) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        is = con.getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("NETWORK ERROR #1", e.getMessage());
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("NETWORK ERROR #2 ", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("NETWORK ERROR #3", e.getMessage());
            }

            jsonString = sb.toString();
        }
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main2Activity extends ListActivity {

//JSON URL
private static String url = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8eTR5TXv";

private static final String ALBUMS = "album";

private static final String C_ALBUMS = "c_album";
private static final String C_ARTISTS = "c_artist";
private static final String C_DATES = "c_date";
private static final String C_RATINGS = "c_rating";
private static final String C_PICS = "c_pic";

JSONArray albumType = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    //Turn off StrictMode
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
            ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSON jParser = new JSON();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        albumType = json.getJSONArray(ALBUMS);

        for(int i = 0; i < albumType.length(); i++){
            JSONObject a = albumType.getJSONObject(i);

            String cAlbum = a.getString(C_ALBUMS);
            String cArtist = a.getString(C_ARTISTS);
            String cDate = a.getString(C_DATES);
            String cRating = a.getString(C_RATINGS);
            String cPic = a.getString(C_PICS);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(C_ALBUMS, cAlbum);
            map.put(C_ARTISTS, cArtist);
            map.put(C_DATES, cDate);
            map.put(C_RATINGS, cRating);
            map.put(C_PICS, cPic);

            contactList.add(map);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            contactList,
            R.layout.row2,
            new String[] { C_ALBUMS, C_ARTISTS, C_DATES, C_RATINGS, C_PICS },
            new int[] {R.id.tv_albumName, R.id.tv_Artist, R.id.tv_Date, R.id.tv_Rating, R.id.tv_pic}
    );

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and the XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ALBUM_NAME"
    android:id="@+id/tv_albumName"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ARTIST"
    android:id="@+id/tv_Artist"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_albumName"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_albumName"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_albumName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/DATE"
    android:id="@+id/tv_Date"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Artist"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_Artist"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_Artist" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/RATING"
    android:id="@+id/tv_Rating"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Date"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_Date"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_Date" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_pic"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_Date"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:padding="1sp"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you run the app, does it show anything or give any errors?

Comment: Sorry, added adapter. If I run the app with my current code, it all works, the images just don't show

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: Please share what are you getting in logcat detail, that would be helpful to investigate what is happing wrong in the code.

Comment: The way you write the code its obvious you are trying to set the URL to ImageView... It's not possible. After you acheive the URL you have to download the image and then you can display it. Use some of the known libraries like the other people suggest.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will look into using image loader libraries

Comment: If any answer is useful to you then accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use **Image Loader** Libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

May this link will helpful to use [Introduction to Glide, Image Loader Library for Android, recommended by Google](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

#### Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
    .into(ivImg);
```

#### Glide:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
    .into(ivImg);
```

Or You can try [Universal Image Loader Library in Android](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android)

```
//your image url
String url = "Your Image URL";

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(fallback)
                .showImageOnFail(fallback)
                .showImageOnLoading(fallback).build();

//initialize image view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)     

//download and display image from url
imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple library to display images in Android ListView. Images are being downloaded asynchronously in the background. Images are being cached on SD card and in memory.

Get LazyList from [here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

```
ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
...
imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView);
```

Don't forget to add the following permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: imageLoader.DisplayImage("contactlist.get(position).get("c_pic")", imageView); could be more usefull i guess.